# Ask for help according to samsung Galaxy Gio GT s5660

Tags: locked-out, samsung-galaxy-gio

I am honestly ask any professional who have an idea about Samsung. I forgot my password i made by my own. as a result, i cant do anything on my phone right now. i can't get through the screen. because I've forgotten my password. could anyone help please?
Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

Insert a wrong password again and again (maybe trying to remember the correct one). At a certain point (after several tries), you will be asked something like "Forgot your password?" and then you should be able to unlock the phone with your google account.

Of course, you must have had associate your google account with your phone.

This way works on some phones, I hope it works on yours too.

Comment: i did it for many times. but it didn't work